# how to make global function for multiple buttons ( javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a quiz and for each questin there is a "show hint" button, for each hint, i want to make a single global function ( for clean code purposes) that hides the sentance below it.

it works for one of the buttons for Question 1, but not question 2,3,4

I know this super basic but iam fairly new to JS and i could really appreciate some help, thank you in advance.

```js
function seeHint() {
  const hintBtn = document.querySelector(".hintBtn");
  const message = document.querySelector(".msg");

  hintBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    message.classList.toggle("hidehint");
  });

}
```

```css
.showhint {
  display: block;
}

.hidehint {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Syne:wght@585&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class=" container text-center">
  <button type="button" class="hintBtn btn btn-secondary" onclick="seeHint()">Need a Hint?</button>
  <button type="button" class="ansbtn btn btn-info">Answers</button>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <div class="msg hidehint">
      <p>this is a hint for Question 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are all of the questions on the same page? If yes, I suggest either using unique IDs for each question, or using 'this' for better targeting of hints. If you provide a better example, it'd be easier to help.

Comment: Hi all, ive edited it

Comment: It would probably be easier if you added in the first question text and at least one more question/hint set of HTML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed your markup and CSS a little bit in order to make it a bit easier, there you go.

```js
const questions = document.getElementsByClassName("question"); //Get all questions

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) { //Iterate for each one of the questions

  questions[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) { //Attach an event listener on the question, in order to understand this a bit better search for event delegation in JS
    if(e.target.classList[0] == "hintBtn") { //Check if the target that triggered the event is the hint button
      this.getElementsByClassName('msg')[0].classList.toggle("hidehint"); //Inside every question find the message and toggle the class
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.hidehint {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Syne:wght@585&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="question container text-center">
  <button type="button" class="hintBtn btn btn-secondary">Need a Hint?</button>
  <button type="button" class="ansbtn btn btn-info">Answers</button>


  <div class="text-center">
    <div class="msg hidehint">
      <p>this is a hint for Question 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="question container text-center">
  <button type="button" class="hintBtn btn btn-secondary">Need a Hint?</button>
  <button type="button" class="ansbtn btn btn-info">Answers</button>


  <div class="text-center">
    <div class="msg hidehint">
      <p>this is a hint for Question 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="question container text-center">
  <button type="button" class="hintBtn btn btn-secondary">Need a Hint?</button>
  <button type="button" class="ansbtn btn btn-info">Answers</button>


  <div class="text-center">
    <div class="msg hidehint">
      <p>this is a hint for Question 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, so ive tried inserting this into my code and added the changes u made to the html, but it still wont work? do i need to change the js?

Comment: this is the error im getting:                            Uncaught TypeError: this.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined

Comment: Is it possible upload your code on codepen or somewhere similar to tell you what's wrong?

Comment: sure , https://codepen.io/shuibcodes/pen/GRZeBjj   the javasctip thats important is on line 82

Comment: You were missing some classes and you had set `display: none` inline to the hints. Check this https://codepen.io/vmank/pen/gOrEjGW

Comment: sorry can u tell me which file you changed?

Comment: it wokred thank you , but can u tell me which classes was i missng?

Comment: I have wrapped the buttons and the hint inside a `div` with a class `question`, some of these wrappers were missing. Some other classes that were missing were the `hintBtn` and the `hintint` that are also crucial for the JS code to work. A friendly suggestion is to indent your code while also keeping separate(new lines) different chunks of code(ex. question1 from question2). It will help you locate problems faster in the future and it will also be more readable.